# Changing UIImageView from normal to highlighted doesn't work

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I've got a UIImageView as the background of my UITableViewCell subclass. I have put an image in the Image field and a lighter version of that image in the Highlighted field. In my UITableViewCell subclass, I added code to set that ImageView to highlighted, but nothing changes...

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    // Configure the view for the selected state
    self.backgroundImageView.highlighted = selected;
    NSLog(@"selected: %d", selected);
}
```

I've verified that self.backgroundImageView is properly connected as an IBOutlet.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize the UIImageView like this:

```
[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gray_arrow"] highlightedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"white_arrow"]];
```

If you need to keep it highlighted, in your tableview's didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, get the subview that represents your UIImageView and make it highlighted. Something like this:

```
UIImageView* imageView = [[[dataSource objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] subviews] objectAtIndex:2]
[imageView setHighlighted:YES];
```

Set the UIImageView's in the other cells to :

```
 [imageView setHighlighted:NO];
```